# sql server 2008 sp1 installation problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am installing sql server 2008 sp1 <strike>enterprise</strike> developer edition. But I am unable to install the sql server 2008 sp1. I have Vs 2008 sp1(professional edition) installed on my laptop. Do i need to uninstall Vs 2008 sp1 to install Sql server 2008 sp1. Please let me know Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to uninstall VS to install SS. You might get more help over at serverfault.com.

Comment: You're installing Enterprise Edition on a laptop? Does your laptop meet the [Hardware and Software Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) for Enterprise Edition (especially the O/S requirements)?

Comment: Hi Joe,

Sorry Its developer edition. My laptop meets the hardware and software requirements.

Comment: Can you provide any more details on the installation failure? Any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues with installing SQL over a SQL Express install (which comes with VS 2008).  A quick search turned up instructions on how to remove the Express components.  It's for 2005, but I believe these are still applicable:

http://www.jwc3.net/2008/05/installing-sql-server-2005-after-visual.html

Hope this helps.